# How to expand and count consecutively in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, expand, panel-data

How do you expand a dataset and count consecutively by year?

Specifically, my dataset has 15 rows and 4 columns: the firm ID, sector code, year and month. This data has 15 monthly information over 2 years. A firm that took a monthly action is observed on that month. If every firm was observed each month, I would have had 30obs. I want to expand the data so that a firm that did not take a monthly action is recorded as 0 and a firm that did take an action is recorded as 1. I generate a series of 3 variables. The first is Treat, which equals 1 if a firm was previously in the dataset, and 0 if the firm's obs is added (because they did not take an action on that month). For example, firm 1 will have six 1s whereas firm 2 will get a . when month=3 and year=2010. Next, I generate Treat2, which replaces . with 0 and keeps the 1s unchanged. Finally, I generate a variable Treat3, which counts whether a given firm has consecutively taken an action at least three times within a year.

Here is what the original data looks like:

| Firm_ID1 | Sector | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2010 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2010 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2010 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2010 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2010 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2010 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2011 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2011 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2011 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2011 | 3 |

Here is what I am looking for

| Firm_ID1 | Sector | Year | Month | Treat | Treat1 | Treat2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2010 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2010 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2010 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2011 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2010 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2010 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2010 | 3 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2011 | 3 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2010 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2010 | 2 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2010 | 3 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2011 | 1 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2011 | 2 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 2011 | 3 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2010 | 1 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2010 | 2 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2010 | 3 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2011 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2011 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 2011 | 3 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2010 | 1 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2010 | 2 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2010 | 3 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2011 | 1 | . | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2011 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2011 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

This what I try without success:

```
  dfdata1 <- dfdata %>%
    group_by(Firm_ID1,Year)%>%
    mutate(isconsecutive =duplicated(rbind(dfdata, transform(dfdata, Month=Month+1), transform(dfdata, Month= Month-1)), fromLast = TRUE)[1:nrow(dfdata)]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a different `data.table` approach... not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it's how I would approach things

```
library(data.table)
# cast to wide and calculate length
new_DT <- dcast(DT, Firm_ID1 + Year ~ Month, value.var = "Firm_ID1", 
                fun.aggregate = length, drop = FALSE)
# calculate year actions
new_DT[, Treat2 := ifelse(rowSums(.SD) >= 3, 1, 0), .SDcols = patterns("^[0-9]+$")][]
#    Firm_ID1 Year 1 2 3 Treat2
# 1:        1 2010 1 1 1      1
# 2:        1 2011 1 1 1      1
# 3:        2 2010 1 1 0      0
# 4:        2 2011 1 1 0      0
# 5:        3 2010 1 0 0      0
# 6:        3 2011 0 0 0      0
# 7:        4 2010 0 0 0      0
# 8:        4 2011 1 1 0      0
# 9:        5 2010 0 0 0      0
#10:        5 2011 0 1 1      0
```

**sample data**

```
DT <- fread("Firm_ID1   Sector  Year    Month
1   1   2010    1
1   1   2010    2
1   1   2010    3
1   1   2011    1
1   1   2011    2
1   1   2011    3
2   1   2010    1
2   1   2010    2
2   1   2011    1
2   1   2011    2
3   1   2010    1
4   2   2011    1
4   2   2011    2
5   2   2011    2
5   2   2011    3")
```

Comment: Thank you Wimpel, it worked with my original data. How can I comie back to the long format and merge the newly obtained dataset new_DT with the original while keeping the Treat2 values for each observation? I tried the melt command but it did not give the expected result.

Comment: `melt(new_DT, measure.vars = patterns("^[0-9]+$"), 
     variable.name = "month", value.name = "Treat1")`

Comment: @ Wimpel
 I have a follow-up question on this. I am trying to use this technique on 4 annual large datasets that have 10 variables each. For each, I have more than 9 million observations once I use the dcast and melt commands. I will then have to merge these datasets into one for my analyses. Do you know if there is a way to handle this without running out of memory?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tidyr`'s `complete` function:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  complete(Firm_ID1, Year, Month) %>% 
  mutate(Treat2 = +!is.na(Sector)) %>% 
  group_by(Firm_ID1, Year) %>% 
  mutate(Treat3 = +all(
    !is.na(Sector), 
    !is.na(lag(Sector, n = 1, default = TRUE)), 
    !is.na(lag(Sector, n = 2, default = TRUE))
    )
    ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 30 x 6
   Firm_ID1  Year Month Sector Treat2 Treat3
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>  <int>
 1        1  2010     1      1      1      1
 2        1  2010     2      1      1      1
 3        1  2010     3      1      1      1
 4        1  2011     1      1      1      1
 5        1  2011     2      1      1      1
 6        1  2011     3      1      1      1
 7        2  2010     1      1      1      0
 8        2  2010     2      1      1      0
 9        2  2010     3     NA      0      0
10        2  2011     1      1      1      0
11        2  2011     2      1      1      0
12        2  2011     3     NA      0      0
13        3  2010     1      1      1      0
14        3  2010     2     NA      0      0
15        3  2010     3     NA      0      0
16        3  2011     1     NA      0      0
17        3  2011     2     NA      0      0
18        3  2011     3     NA      0      0
19        4  2010     1     NA      0      0
20        4  2010     2     NA      0      0
21        4  2010     3     NA      0      0
22        4  2011     1      2      1      0
23        4  2011     2      2      1      0
24        4  2011     3     NA      0      0
25        5  2010     1     NA      0      0
26        5  2010     2     NA      0      0
27        5  2010     3     NA      0      0
28        5  2011     1     NA      0      0
29        5  2011     2      2      1      0
30        5  2011     3      2      1      0
```

I skipped the `.` part for `Treat` one because it breaks the integer type. It's easy to create if neccessary.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I got an error message:Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Treat3 = +...`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: niu = "M000011114444M", exercice = 2017.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! Can't combine `default` <logical> and `x` <character>.

Comment: Replace the `default = TRUE` in the shown code with `default = "1"`.

Comment: I'm still having the same error but I don't understand why. Here's the error message: Can't combine `default` <double> and `x` <character>.  Could you please explain this part when you create Treat3 variable?   Many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `str(data)` (or how your data.frame is named) or `sapply(data, typeof)`. `Sector` should be a numeric variable. If `Sector` is a character vector: Did you replace `default = TRUE` with `default = "1"`? Mind the "".

Comment: Thanks so much Martin, it worked as I wanted.